# Use IF with multiple ELSEIF and ELSE in a spreadsheet cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make this statement applicable to some cells in my google spreadsheet :

```
if ((B29 - B36) > 0) {
    (B29 - B36) * (D36 / 100) + F35 + F34 + F33
} else if  ((B29 - B35) > 0) {
    (B29 - B35) * (D35 / 100) + F34 + F33);
} else if (B29 - B34 > 0) {
    (B29 - B34) * (D34 / 100) + F33);
} else {
    0
}
```

I tried to make it with only `IF`, but the cells didn't like the syntax :

```
=IF((B29 - B36) > 0);((B29 - B36) * (D36 / 100) + F35 + F34 + F33);IF((B29 - B35) > 0);((B29 - B35) * (D35 / 100) + F34 + F33);IF((B29 - B34) > 0);((B29 - B34) * (D34 / 100) + F33);0
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct syntax would be like this:

```
=IF(B29-B36 > 0; (B29-B36)*(D36/100)+F35+F34+F33;
 IF(B29-B35 > 0; (B29-B35)*(D35/100)+F34+F33;
 IF(B29-B34 > 0; (B29-B34)*(D34/100)+F33; 0)))
```